# elementary OS 5.0 Juno graphic tablet support

Tags: release-juno, elementary-project, tablet

I hope this finds you well

I am currently running a dual boot system with linux elementary OS 5.0 Juno and windows 10. However each OS is on a different drive since my laptop has too drives. I also have a Huion graphic tablet and it is the inspiroy  H640p and i tried connecting it to my laptop, however elementary OS didn't even realize that there is a peripheral connected. I tried installing the drivers from `digimend-kernel-drivers-master` . I tried both ways as a `clone`, `make` and `install` way and trying the debian package way. No matter what I try to do nothing works out as elementary OS doesn't even acknowledge that there is a connected device. I tried manipulating the configuration yet nothing worked.

I downloaded the required driver for my tablet as it also should be supported. I should have the X.org drivers too as i did some of the commands but non worked. I also have secure boot disabled as their website suggested

My system:

1. Quad-Core Intel® Core™ i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
2. Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
3. NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
4. 16.3 GB memory
5. 78.2 GB storage (SATA SSD) (the boot drive for linux , there is alos another drive for windows)

**The website**: https://digimend.github.io/drivers/

Please if anyone has a suggestion, I would love to hear it .
Thank you for reading, I hope you have a great day

Comment: I'd Google for an Ubuntu 18.04 solution in this case, and, if unsuccessful go to ubuntuforums.org and seek support as well. There a a lot of highly experienced users in there. If you find an answer, come back here and post it and accept it.

Comment: If you update Juno to Hera and Update the kernel now taht works?  You can update the kernel in Hera with `sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`